# How to integrate google analytics account with tealium?

Tags: google-analytics, tealium

Any one explains how to integrate google analytics account with tealium ?
What is the usage and purpose of tealium ?
Kindly share the steps to integrate google analytics account with tealium with screen shots.

Comment: This is too broad and vague for a Stack Overflow question; you should probably do some research of your own first. A search for „tealium google analytics“ turns up a page specifically about the subject; as to what Tealium is, have you checked their web site?

Answer (score 1):

The integration is pretty simple (I use Tealium every day). You create a new tag (you can even select a GA template) and fill it in with your GA tracking code. Once you publish your changes the tracking will be live on your site/app.

Tealium is a tag & data management tool. It's like Google Tag Manager where you simply add a tag and deploy it to your site. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote "Any one explains how to integrate google analytics account with tealium ?"

We have several documents on our Community regarding Google Analytics integration. You can find many of them here: https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tags/SERIES-Google-Universal-Analytics/ta-p/9494?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=google-analytics-integration. Please note you will need a Tealium iQ Tag Management account to be able to see the documentation.

> Blockquote "What is the usage and purpose of tealium ?"

We are a tag manager solution for starters. If you wish to use the entire suite of our products and services we can also help with marketing automation and act as a enterprise data hub for all of you offline and online data.

I hope this helps. Thank you and have a great rest of your day.

Regards,

Kathleen Jo

Comment: Is there any way to integrate telium once and have all paged tracked? actually as developer I am being asked to at the telium code in each page of our web mobile app by changing the `xiti_s2` value

Comment: Hello @albanx. We do have this post on the Tealium Learning Community that could help:

Comment: I clicked "Add Comment" too quickly there. Does this document answer your question at all?

https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Mobile-Libraries/Setting-up-a-Google-Universal-Analytics-for-Mobile/ta-p/5585?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=google-analytics-integration

Let me know.

Comment: thank you for the doc. I will have a look and see how I can create a generic configuration, if possible without need of developing. What probably I will need is something like this https://github.com/Tealium/integration-angularjs/blob/master/tealium_angular.js but not sure yet